# undefined method 'has_attached_file' with paperclip on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, paperclip

Rails server will not start after install of paperclip. I have this error message in the console:

```
undefined method 'has_attached_file'.
```

In my Gemfile

```
gem "paperclip", :git => "http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
```

I tried this in my config/environments/development.rb

```
config.gem "paperclip"
```

and this in my config/application.rb

```
Paperclip::Railtie.insert
```

I have ImageMagik installed on my computer (I'm on windows 10). Any clue ?

I had a message in the console after install of paperclip, saying that paperclip is now compatible with aws-sdk >= 2.0.0. So I also set the latest aws-sdk-ruby from github...

EDIT : also tried this after getting the path with the command 'which convert'

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/c/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16/convert"
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd change is to use a version number instead of getting the package directly from GitHub.

in `Gemfile`:

**Change**

```
gem "paperclip", :git => "http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
```

**To**

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 6.0"
```

Make sure to run the `rails generate paperclip` command (example: `rails generate paperclip photo image`) to add the needed `attachment` field to your database model schema.

Once you have the `attachment` field you can use `has_attached_file` to mount paperclip to that field (example: `has_attached_file :image`).

And don't forget to restart your server.

P.S: There's no need to use `config.gem "paperclip"` and `Paperclip::Railtie.insert`, I wasn't able to find any mention of them in the GitHub Paperclip documentation so I'm sure they are discontinued now as they were used in pre Rails 4 applications.

*P.P.S: I would strongly recommend you dual boot to a Unix operating system (be it a Linux distribution or macOS) or use an online IDE such as Cloud9 instead of using Windows. It's simply a bad idea and while working on your project you want to replicate to the smallest detail your production environment.*

Comment: I did all this after recontructing completely my database, as suggested somewhere else. Now the error is no longer raised but I have no attachment set in my form. I am checking and checking again...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
include Paperclip::Glue
```

to your Model.

Comment: It doesn't seem to make any difference in my case.

Comment: If I may ask: You reconstructed your database to fix this, right? Were you able to dump and reimport your legacy database? Was the schema changed?

Comment: I do not notice any change in the schema after dumping and migrating agin. I just followed an advice from someone on a similar topic and it worked for some reason.

Comment: That's strange. Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

I'm all set now. Apparently there was a problem with the database construction. For the rest, everything is well explained on github https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip but 1) I was following a tutorial with a few steps missing and 2) there was a specific problem for windows.

Dropping all the tables and migrating again from scratch seems to have solved the very basic problem which caused the error.

Windows users, pay attention to your path setting of the file.exe which has nothing to do with ImageMagik. You can place this file.exe anywhere you want, in my case

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = 'C:\Sites\utils\GnuWin32\bin'
```

Thanks anyway!